# How to update state before rendering in Reactjs with mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

This is my mobx store code.
First, 'projectGet()' must be executed to push the data from firestore.

```
 @observable projectState = {
    projects: []
  };

  projectGet = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          this.projectState.projects.push(doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  };
```

After push the data into projectState, it should be read at the other .js file.
I ran the function inside of render.
But when I enter the homepage, it doesn't update state at first.
So, when I refresh the homepage, it updates the state.
However, I need to update the state at the first home page access.
I tried to use 'componentWilupdate', 'ComponentDidmount' etc.
It doesn't work at all.
Could you give me some recommendation for this problem?

```
render() {
    const { Project } = this.props;
    Project.projectGet();

    return (
          <div className="col s12 m6">
            <ProjectList projects={Project.projectState.projects} />
          </div>
    );
  }
```

I attached more code below.

```
import React from "react";
import ProjectSummary from "./ProjectSummary";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ProjectList = ({ projects }) => {
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      {projects &&
        projects.map(project => {
          return (
            <Link to={"/project/" + project.id} key={project.id}>
              <ProjectSummary project={project} />
            </Link>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to make API calls before rendering, For example

```
componentDidMount() {
const { Project } = this.props;
Project.projectGet();
}
```

then in render

```
render() {
const { Project } = this.props;
return (
      <div className="col s12 m6">
        <ProjectList projects={Project.projectState.projects} />
      </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you somuch. I tried that. But it works when I redirect to url. I dont' know why it doesn't work on the first access...

Comment: what is the issue you are facing on the first access

Comment: i attached ProjectList.js in my question. That is, when I check the state, the state is already positioned into homepage. And this must be showed through ProjectList.js. But even though, the state is updated, ProjectList doesn't work without redirect to Link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `componendWillMount` to make API call before the component renders, if it is not updated then check whether the expected props are available with `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps({Project}) {
Project.projectGet();
}
```

Once the props are changed you will get the change in the render